# Forward Declaration linker error

Tags: c++, header, forward-declaration

**noobie** programmer here ~

I'm trying to copy some code from my lecture slides, however, the slides don't show the header file setup. Two classes *use* each other (Agent and IBehaviour), so upon recreation I ran into a cyclic include. I tried to use forward declaration solution (in IBehaviour) to solve my problem, however now I'm getting an unresolved external error...'

I think I can see my issue ~ I have a function that is taking in a pointer to an incomplete type in IBehaviour.h, however I don't know how to solve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. The following code has been condensed into h files for reading purposes.

**Agent.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "IBehaviour.h"
#include <list>

class Agent
{
public:
    Agent();
    ~Agent();
    void Update();

protected:
    std::list<IBehaviour*> m_behaviours;
};

Agent::Agent()
{
}

Agent::~Agent()
{
}

void Agent::Update()
{
    for (auto iter = m_behaviours.begin(); iter != m_behaviours.end(); iter++)
        (*iter)->Update(this);
}
```

**IBehaviour.h**

```
class Agent;

class IBehaviour
{
public:
    IBehaviour();
    ~IBehaviour();

    virtual void Update(Agent* pAgent);
};

IBehaviour::IBehaviour()
{
}


IBehaviour::~IBehaviour()
{
}

void IBehaviour::Update(Agent * pAgent)
{
}
```

**SeekB**

```
#pragma once
#include "IBehaviour.h"

class SeekB : public IBehaviour
{
public:
    SeekB();
    ~SeekB();

    void Update(Agent *pAgent) override;
};

SeekB::SeekB()
{
}


SeekB::~SeekB()
{
}

void SeekB::Update(Agent * pAgent)
{
    // Apply seek force to pAgent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `IBehaviour.h` only deals with a pointer to class `Agent`, and has no implementations that make use of that pointer, the forward declaration is fine.

When you start to *use* that pointer, then you need to have included the full class declaration rather than just a forward declaration. I assume your `SeekB` class is *using* the `Agent` class rather than just holding a pointer to it, so you will need to `#include "Agent.h"` in your `SeekB.h` file.

Other than that, I see no cyclic includes in your code...

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I have removed the seek class all together. The issue is between the Agent and the IBehaviour class. I have attempted to remove all cyclic includes, however the program still wont compile...

Error is:

unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int_cdecl invoke_main(void)"(?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Comment: May want to add the `main()` function then.  ;-)  On the plus side, you can at least know you're doing forward declarations properly after all!

Answer (score 0):

Lord have mercy I didn't have a main function. Sorry fam